# macOS Big Sur - How do I dismiss permission request prompts?

Tags: big-sur, permission

[image]

Sometimes when using an app I don't want to grant the app certain permission right away, and I don't want to deny the permission because if I have to grant the permission later, I have to manually go to Sys Prefs to do it.

Is there a way to dismiss permission request prompts like the one shown above?

Comment: What do you expect after dismissing the request: would the app be allowed or not?

Comment: @lhf Neither. Just like the app had never requested the permission.

Comment: That's not an option. It is either Don't Allow or Allow (OK). There is no way to dismiss the prompt without taking action other than quitting the application.  The only remedy is, as you state, to go to System Preferences and grant permission (or conversely) remove permission.

Comment: I don't think quitting the app would make the prompt disappear. @IconDaemon
I wish there's another way to do this.

Comment: Well, the correctly written app should, if you don't provide either answer, come right back and ask the question again.  Since it's asking, it needs the authority for *something* it's about to do.

Comment: I think it's a macOS issue, rather than an app issue. @MarcWilson